# Better alias writing with interleaved single and double-quote characters

Tags: bash, escaping

Any cleaner way to write the following alias with respect to escaping?

`alias bs="echo \'{'\"'account'\"':'\"'a1'\"','\"'portfolio'\"':'\"'p1'\"'}\' | nc 0 9000"`

Yikes, that's pretty ugly; but it works. When I expand the alias (with `C-M-e`) I want this exact result:

`echo '{"account":"a1","portfolio":"p1"}' | nc 0 9000`

I'm curious to know if I'm missing a trick: curious, mostly.

Comment: Can you put what is inside the alias quotes in a $()?  So, `alias bs="$(echo '{"your stuff"}' ...)"`?

Comment: Alias expansion seems to involve an extra round of quote removal which suggests your solution may be as good as it gets. I played around with the `$'...'` construct to no avail. Take a look at the output of `alias bs` for your alias to see how messy it can *really* get.

Comment: "As good as it gets" - yes, I was afraid someone might say so(!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be an alias?

```
function bs { echo '{"account":"a1","portfolio":"p1"}' | nc 0 9000; }
```

Comment: That's a reasonable question. I wanted an alias so that I could employ sed and friends and manipulate the command further on the command line prior to issuing it, which I can't do with a command. I realize functions can take arguments(!) but I use so many different combinations of the invocation so as to make a function more trouble than it's worth.